# Comments & experience with hibernate-generic-dao and the likes?

Tags: java, hibernate, open-source, dao, appfuse

I had a hard time writing my own generic search method (Using SearchCriteria DTO) in my DAO's. So I decided to look for a generic DAO Open-Source library and see how they do it.

I've been reading [hibernate-generic-dao](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) since this morning and it looks good (looking at the sample maven project (spring,hibernate,h2,spring-mvc).

But I thought I should get the expert's opinion first before deciding to use `hibernate-generic-dao`.

Looking at other related SO posts, I've also seen other related libraries that looks stable

1. [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home)
2. [j-genericdao](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html)
3. [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades)

All experiences or opinions are greatly appreciated :) thanks a lot in advance

**UPDATE**:
Looking at Appfuse's [GenericDAOHibernate interface](http://static.appfuse.org/appfuse-hibernate/apidocs/org/appfuse/dao/hibernate/GenericDaoHibernate.html). It looks like they only provide minimal CRUD operations. Is this right? Then I'll cross-out Appfuse from the list

Answer (score 3):

[Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades) is great, I used it in some Project.

But the Hades project moved into [Spring-Data-JPA](http://www.springsource.org/node/3074). It look like Hades, work like Hades and the project lead is the same. And Spring-Data-JPA contains some new features not aviable in Hades, like queryDsl.

Comment: I was trying hard to find a reliable and active JPA DAO open source. Great to hear Spring actually has it. Are all tutorials on web about Hades still valid for spring-Data-JPA? Thanks

Comment: @CK Lee: I don't know ALL tutorials on web about Hades, but the general way how spring-Data-JPA works is still the same. One different is the configuration, it differs from Hades in some details: there seems to be more magic in spring-Data-JPA, so you do not need to instanciate the Custom-DAO-Impl by your own. -- But have a look at the Reference Documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M2 /reference/html/   -- it is only 26 Pages, so you should it read!